# How to duplicate an object with random start frame?

Tags: animation

I created an animation, a creature is walking. I would like to duplicate it several times in one scene but with different start frame. For example, obj1 starts from frame #5, obj2 starts from frame #10 . This way they don't look like they are the same object. How can I do that? 
BTW, I am using Cycles.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

duplicate your character (**shift+D**) then right click to keep it in the same place above your original character

then shift the new duplicated character by changing the value of delta location/rotation/scale (**object tab > delta transform**)

[image]

now you have two distinct objects moving together, you can shift the keyframes of the second object in the dope sheet editor (**b** to box select all keyframes then g to move them)

[image]

now you have two objects with two shifted animations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Shifting keyframes is not helping. Suppose that I have a walking character from frame #1 to #200. I want to have a second character which his move starts from frame #10 which means that the old frame #10 is his first frame (frame#1). This way both characters at frame #1 have different move. Does it make sense?

Comment: I have found this script but it did not work for my object. http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/544-arewo-gui-addon-video-tutorial.html

Comment: I updated my answer with more details, I hope that helps :)